# How do I reject/answer call in Android 2.3.3?

Tags: android

I am trying to reject/answer a call in android 2.3.3. I tried using ITelephony-`endcall()` and `answerRingingCall()` with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

How to answer an incoming call:

```
/**
 * Emulates a headset button press to accept the call
 * 
 * @param context
 *            A context to use
 */
public static void answerPhoneHeadsethook(Context context) {
    // Simulate a press of the headset button to pick up the call
    // SettingsClass.logMe(tag, "Simulating headset button");
    Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

    // froyo and beyond trigger on buttonUp instead of buttonDown
    Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
}
```

As far as I am concerned, there is no way to reject calls in 2.3+ (it would be possible to accept and reject the call with the method above, but then the caller has to pay for it).

Comment: Sorry for the rookie question but I am calling this method from my activity. What should I use instead of context(getapplicationcontext?)?

Comment: `YOURACTIVITY.this` - and it is always better to use `this` than `getApplicationContext`

Comment: It is working on my Emulater but not on my device- HTC Incredible S....Any idea???

Comment: Hm, actually it should be working on any device. It does work on all my devices... sorry, can't help you with that then...

Answer (score 1):

Needed to send this intent before!!

```
Intent headSetUnPluggedintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
              headSetUnPluggedintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
              headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("state", 1);
              headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("name", "Headset");

              // TODO: Should we require a permission?
             sendOrderedBroadcast(headSetUnPluggedintent, null);
```